# Как избавиться от черного фона сзади у png и gif изображение при загрузке в PHP

Tags: изображения, php, классы

Есть класс на PHP, для уменьшения размера изображений http://pastebin.com/TfMhh9iq

И при уменьшении png и gif изображений с прозрачным фоном, им добавляется черный фон сзади. Как назначить свой фон, т.е белый?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**upd:** http://pastebin.com/T5aRNtph наверное так, проверить не на чем ;)

почитать про `imageAlphaBlending` и `imageSaveAlpha`
Пример для `png`, для `gif` я думаю будет аналогично

```
<?php
/**
Небольшой скрипт для уменьшения изображения
*/
// Создаём ресурс из исходного изображения - в формает png 24
$res = imageCreateFromPng('file_name.png');

// Узнаём информацию об изображении
$prop = getimagesize('file_name.png');

// Задаём в переменных новую ширину и высоту
$newWidth = 200;
$newHeight = 200;

/**
*  Создаём новый ресурс с нужной шириной и высотой,
*   в который запишем исходный ресурс,
*   заметим, что изображение полноцветное - imageCreateTrueColor
*/
$tmp = imageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);

/**
 Перед тем как произодить опрерации с новым ресурсом,
 установим некоторые опции
 imageAlphaBlending - устанавливает режим смешивания(режим
 смешивания недоступен для изображений с палитрой)
 по умолчанию для truecolor изображений - true, для изображений
 с палитрой - false
 true/false - включен/выключен

        true - при накладывании одного изображения на другое
        цвета пикселей нижележащего и накладываемого изображения смешиваются,
        параметры смешивания определяются прозрачностью пикселя.

        false - накладываемый пиксель заменяет исходный
*/
imageAlphaBlending($tmp, false);
/*
ImageSaveAlpha
Сохранять или не сохранять информацию о прозрачности
по умолчанию - false, а надо true
*/
imageSaveAlpha($tmp, true);

/*
Всё, теперь прозрачность должна сохранятся
*/

/*
копируем исходное изображение с новое, в новый ресурс
*/
imageCopyResampled($tmp, $res, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth,
$newHeight, $prop[0], $prop[1]);

// Говорим браузеру о типе изображения. Тип - PNG
header("Content-Type: image/png");

// Выводим изображение в буффер
imagePng($tmp);

?>
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T5aRNtph наверное так, проверить не на чем ;)

Comment: либо, если не прокатит, возможно надо будет переместить в место, где изображение создается только

Comment: @thunder, не прокатило :( А где изображение создаётся?

Comment: ищите функции начинающиеся с imageCreateTrueColor -- это функции создания изображения из исходника, посмотрите мой пример в первом ответе, там все прокомментировано какая функция что делает ;)

Comment: @thunder, о дааааааа! Я сделал это! Спасибо Вам большое :*

Comment: та пожалуйста :) все просто же)

Answer (score 5):

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));

imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
```

Comment: я быстрее ;)

Comment: @thunder да я пока вспомнил, пока написал :-)

Comment: ну пока вспомнил, пока поискал пример... ;)

Comment: @thunder честно признаюсь - писал по памяти :-) ибо сам озадачивался этим, в поиске такой пример довольно часто встречается.

Comment: @lampa, плохо знаю где и что, но не поможете запихнуть это в класс http://pastebin.com/TfMhh9iq?

Comment: а если подумать, посмотрев мой пример  и проследив порядок действий? ;)

Comment: @thunder, я как только не пробывал уже :) Наверно потому, что я не знаю, в какое именно место ставить :(

Comment: ну так мыж не знаем) пока что это выглядит как "сделайте все за меня, я ничего не понимаю и не хочу разбираться" ;)

Comment: @thunder, ясно, понятно.

Answer (score 1):

> Пример для png, для gif я думаю будет аналогично

К сожалению у меня для gif такой способ не подошел, изучив документацию нашел решение.
Для .gif файлов необходимо пропустить изображение через
[imagecolortransparent()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolortransparent.php) перед этим задав цвет который мы хотим сделать прозрачным, т.е. чёрный.

Еще мы должны оставить параметр **imageAlphaBlending() - TRUE**

```
$res = imageCreateFromPng('file_name.png');  
$prop = getimagesize('file_name.png');    
$newWidth = 200;
$newHeight = 200;
$tmp = imageCreateTrueColor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$black = imagecolorallocate($tmp , 0, 0, 0);
imageAlphaBlending($tmp, true);
imageSaveAlpha($tmp, true);
imagecolortransparent ($tmp, $black);
imageCopyResampled($tmp, $res, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth,
$newHeight, $prop[0], $prop[1]);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagePng($tmp);
```

Это сработало для меня.